# How to convert a string variable to an Array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a string value like this: `{"id": "312749", "315082", "316379", "316648", "320454", "321766"}`
I would like it to be read as an array in python. Ids as the table name and the ids values as variables of the array.
I'm learning python I guess I must not be using the right terms for my search, I didn't find the solution. Could you help me?

Comment: This variable is not a valid string, can you paste the exact string you are working with ?

Comment: this seems like a broken data format

Comment: Are you sure that's what your string looks like? It's not a valid string representation of any standard Python object. Please clarify what you mean by 'array'. Do you mean a *numpy* array or do you really mean a Python list. What is your expected output?

Comment: oops sorry the format was incorrect, while trying to modify the data I made a small mistake, I just updated original post. Data come from a CSV file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the OP really means a list rather than a [numpy] array, this would work:

```
import re
from numpy import array
STRING = '{"ids": 319242, 322456, 327484"}'
LIST = [int(n) for n in re.findall('\d+', STRING)]
print(LIST)
ARRAY = array(LIST)
print(ARRAY)
```

**Output:**

```
[319242, 322456, 327484]
[319242 322456 327484]
```

**EDIT:**

Added numpy array